# About parametric equation of a line in $3$-space

Tags: analytic-geometry, vectors, parametric

> $a.$ Given coordinates $(x, y, z )$ with origin $(0,0,0)$, parameterize the line
>   through the points $(4,5,6)$ and $(1,2,3).$
>
> $b.$ Take components of your answer to Part $(a)$ to give three scalar equations
>   parameterizing $l$: $x(t) = \ldots, y(t) = \ldots, z(t) = \ldots$

$a.$ Let $(x, y, z), (4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3)$ be $3$ vectors all originating at $(0, 0, 0).$ Let $l$ be a line passing through the head of those $3$ vectors. Then by head-to-tail method, $(4, 5, 6) - (1, 2, 3)$ is a vector on $l$. Scaling it by $t$ gives us another vector $t((4, 5, 6) - (1, 2, 3))$ on $t$. Then by head-to-tail method, $(x, y, z) = t(4, 5, 6) + (1 - t)(1, 2, 3).$

$b.$ $x(t) = 4t + (1 - t) = 3t + 1.$

$y(t) = 5t + 2 - 2t = 3t + 2.$

$z(t) = 3t + 3.$

Does that make sense?

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: [Linked](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115686/what-is-the-vector-equation-of-the-line-through-the-head-of-v-0-and-parallel-t/1117245#1117245).